# Numbering inside grouped array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, json, underscore.js

Need to perform a grouping of an object in the below manner (With the numbering of questions):

```
1. Header 1
 Subheader 1
  1.1 Question 1
  1.2 Question 2
 Subheader 2
  1.3 Question 1
  1.4 Question 2
2. Header 2
 Subheader 1
  2.1 Question 1
 Subheader 2
  2.2 Question 2
```

Successful at grouping in the above manner using underscore-js. But i need continuous numbering for the questions inside a header which i am not able to achieve. Please refer the jsfiddle which i have created.

Partial Solution : I can get the length of the number of questions using which i can build the logic but every time my $index gets reset for every loop due to which i am unable get the total count of questions inside a header.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="y in grid" ng-init="headerIndex = $index ;">{{headerIndex + 1 }}. &nbsp;{{headers[headerIndex]}}
  <div ng-repeat="x in y" ng-init="subHeaderIndex = $index;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{{x[0].sub_header_text}}
{{x.length}}
          <div ng-repeat="z in x " ng-init="questionIndex = $index">          
      &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;          
        {{headerIndex + 1 }}.{{( (subHeaderIndex) * (x.length)) + (questionIndex + 1)}}
        {{z.question_text}}
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.grid = {"Header in English template of German Country":{"SubHeader in English template in German Country":[{"question_text":"sadsad","header_text":"Header in English template of German Country","sub_header_text":"SubHeader in English template in German Country","question_version":1,"question_id":151113,"position_id":101,"template_id":194941,"question_typ":"Text","mandatory_field":"false","status":"new","minimum_value":"null","maximum_value":"null"},{"question_text":"sadsaddsa","header_text":"Header in English template of German Country","sub_header_text":"SubHeader in English template in German Country","question_version":1,"question_id":232366,"position_id":101,"template_id":194941,"question_typ":"Text","mandatory_field":"false","status":"new","minimum_value":"null","maximum_value":"null"}],"SubHeader in English template of German Country":[{"question_text":"sadsaddsa","header_text":"Header in English template of German Country","sub_header_text":"SubHeader in English template of German Country","question_version":1,"question_id":162308,"position_id":101,"template_id":194941,"question_typ":"Text","mandatory_field":"false","status":"new","minimum_value":"null","maximum_value":"null"},{"question_text":"sadsadsad","header_text":"Header in English template of German Country","sub_header_text":"SubHeader in English template of German Country","question_version":1,"question_id":198190,"position_id":101,"template_id":194941,"question_typ":"Text","mandatory_field":"false","status":"new","minimum_value":"null","maximum_value":"null"},{"question_text":"sadsadsad","header_text":"Header in English template of German Country","sub_header_text":"SubHeader in English template of German Country","question_version":1,"question_id":204945,"position_id":101,"template_id":194941,"question_typ":"Numeric","mandatory_field":"false","status":"new","minimum_value":"null","maximum_value":"null"}],"sub Header 2":[{"question_text":"dsfdsfdsf","header_text":"Header in English template of German Country","sub_header_text":"sub Header 2","question_version":1,"question_id":166093,"position_id":101,"template_id":194941,"question_typ":"Text","mandatory_field":"true","status":"new","minimum_value":"null","maximum_value":"null"}]},"First Header creation":{"First Sub Header creation":[{"question_text":"sadsad","header_text":"First Header creation","sub_header_text":"First Sub Header creation","question_version":1,"question_id":160341,"position_id":101,"template_id":194941,"question_typ":"Text","mandatory_field":"false","status":"new","minimum_value":"null","maximum_value":"null"}]},"Header for testing":{"SUb header to Czech Republic":[{"question_text":"sadsad","header_text":"Header for testing","sub_header_text":"SUb header to Czech Republic","question_version":1,"question_id":181485,"position_id":101,"template_id":194941,"question_typ":"Text","mandatory_field":"false","status":"new","minimum_value":"null","maximum_value":"null"},{"question_text":"sadsadsad","header_text":"Header for testing","sub_header_text":"SUb header to Czech Republic","question_version":1,"question_id":226726,"position_id":101,"template_id":194941,"question_typ":"Text","mandatory_field":"false","status":"new","minimum_value":"null","maximum_value":"null"},{"question_text":"sadsadsad","header_text":"Header for testing","sub_header_text":"SUb header to Czech Republic","question_version":1,"question_id":238704,"position_id":101,"template_id":194941,"question_typ":"Text","mandatory_field":"false","status":"new","minimum_value":"null","maximum_value":"null"}],"subheadertest":[{"question_text":"sadsad","header_text":"Header for testing","sub_header_text":"subheadertest","question_version":1,"question_id":212819,"position_id":101,"template_id":194941,"question_typ":"Y/N","mandatory_field":"false","status":"new","minimum_value":"null","maximum_value":"null"}]},"Header Title":{"sab tilte":[{"question_text":"dsfdsfdsf","header_text":"Header Title","sub_header_text":"sab tilte","question_version":1,"question_id":204747,"position_id":101,"template_id":194941,"question_typ":"Text","mandatory_field":"true","status":"new","minimum_value":"null","maximum_value":"null"},{"question_text":"dsfdsfdsf","header_text":"Header Title","sub_header_text":"sab tilte","question_version":1,"question_id":234628,"position_id":101,"template_id":194941,"question_typ":"Text","mandatory_field":"false","status":"new","minimum_value":"null","maximum_value":"null"}],"sub header":[{"question_text":"dsfdsfdsfdsf","header_text":"Header Title","sub_header_text":"sub header","question_version":1,"question_id":243346,"position_id":101,"template_id":194941,"question_typ":"Text","mandatory_field":"true","status":"new","minimum_value":"null","maximum_value":"null"}]}};

    $scope.headers = Object.keys($scope.grid);
}
```

JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/mdaamir1989/Lvc0u55v/10517/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maintain a counter at the controller and increase it on each ng-repeat to get the continuous numbering of questions and reset it on subheader level.

Change your HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="x in y" ng-init="subHeaderIndex = $index;number = resetCounter()">
       &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{{x[0].sub_header_text}}
          {{x.length}}
   <div ng-repeat="z in x" ng-init="questionIndex = $index; number = incrementCounter()">        
          &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;          
            {{headerIndex + 1 }}.{{( (subHeaderIndex) * (x.length)) + (questionIndex + 1)}}
            {{z.question_text}} {{number}}  
   </div>
</div>
```

In Controller

```
$scope.counter = 1;
$scope.resetCounter = function(){
  return $scope.counter = 1;
}
$scope.incrementCounter = function() {
   return $scope.counter++;
}
```

`{{number}}` in HTML will help you in maintaining the continuous numbering for the questions

Updated Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/10556/

Comment: I don't need continuous numbering , as shown in the question i need continuous numbering on questions for all the sub-headers in a header.

Comment: Can you please give me the expected output.

Comment: Hi Please find my updated answer and let me know is that what you need. And please find the updated fiddle

Comment: Perfect , thats what i was looking for. I did try the same solution , but i tried to reset the counter in ng-init instead of writing a method.